# calculate the inverse of the value of qnorm

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate the power. I adapted a formula of Walter to calculate the sample in concordance study. However i need to use it for power calculation when I have the number of subject.

```
calcul_f <- function(alpha,puissance,ccc0,ccc1,nb){

  cat("ccc0 correpond to the concordance to compare et ccc1 the new concordance et nb the number of replicate")
  U_alpha <- abs(qnorm(alpha))
  U_beta <- qnorm(puissance)
  
  A <- ccc0/(1-ccc0)
  B <- ccc1/(1-ccc1)
  C <- (1+(nb*A)) / (1+(nb*B))
  
  
  NSN <- 1+((2*((U_alpha+U_beta)^2)*nb)/(((log(C))^2)*(nb-1)))
  NSN

}

calcul_f (alpha = 0.05,
          puissance = 0.8,
          ccc0 = 0.6,
          ccc1 = 0.75,
          nb = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse function of *qnorm* is *pnorm*:

```
> pnorm(qnorm(0.2))
[1] 0.2
> qnorm(pnorm(4.2))
[1] 4.2
```

This holds for *every* probability distribution, because the quantiles (R functions with prefix *q*) are defined as the inverse function of the cumulative distribution function (R functions with prefix *p*).